# Using validates_with with ruby and mongoid

Tags: ruby, validation, activerecord, exception, mongoid

I'm new to ruby and mongoid. I need to use validates_with and below is the code I have

```
class ValidatorClass < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)

    if record.name == ""

        record.errors.add(:name, "An error occurred")

    end

  end
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated
  include Mongoid::Versioning
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  field :id, type: Integer
  field :name, type: String
  field :age, type: Integer

   validates_with ValidatorClass, :on => :create

end
```

But when I create the model with following code:

```
Person.create(id: 5, name: "", age: 50)
```

I don't get the error thrown. I'm not using Rails. I'm using just ruby with mongodb. Could anybody out there help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, can you try adding this line in class Person:

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to include ActiveModel::Validations on your class

Try changing your validation class to use the code bellow:

```
class ValidatorClass < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.name.blank?
      record.errors.add(:name, "An error occurred")
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It gets into condition. But I'm not receiving the error message "An error occurred".

Comment: Try checking errors like this: a = Person.new -> a.save -> a.errors[:name]. You will see your error. If you call model.create! it will raise a Mongoid::Errors::Validations exception. The model is not persisted when you call Person.new.create, but you can check that it is invalid by calling Person.create.valid?

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Is there anyway I could see and handle the exception raised by Mongoid (Mongoid::Errors::Validations)? thanks.

Comment: Yes. If you want to, you can handle the exception using defaults ruby exception handling: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails-2.1/rails-exception-handling.htm. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
class ValidatorClass < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)

        if !record.name.present?
            record.errors.add(:name, "An error occurred")
        end 

  end
end
```

Comment: As I already said. It gets into condition. But I'm not receiving the error message "An error occurred".